# Frequent Emacs Hangs on WSL2 with Windows 11: Issue with `x-get-selection-internal` and kill and yank

Tags: microsoft-windows, wsl

I'm currently running Emacs 28.2 on WSL2 on Windows 11, utilizing the WSLg to directly open the Emacs GUI from Windows. I'm frequently encountering an issue where the `evil-yank` and `evil-paste-after` commands cause Emacs to hang. When this occurs, the cursor turns into a watch icon, my machine's fan starts spinning rapidly, and I'm unable to use the cut and paste functions. Essentially, Emacs becomes unusable.

I've tried using `toggle-debug-on-quit` to diagnose the issue and each time, the hangup seems to occur at the function `x-get-selection-internal(CLIPBOARD UTF8_STRING nil nil)`. However, I'm at a loss on how to debug this issue further as `x-get-selection-internal` is a C function.

The only workaround I've found so far is to restart WSL2, but the frequency at which this issue occurs (every few hours) makes this solution far from ideal. This issue has become a significant pain point in my Emacs usage on WSL2, and it's added a level of uncertainty as I never know when I'll have to restart WSL2.

Any advice or suggestions from the community would be greatly appreciated.